# match doesn't return capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex, capturing-group

I'm trying to apply a regular expression to a string, in search of any placeholders, but I can't figure out why the result is only the full match, not the capturing group.

```
//----HTML------------------------//    
<p>Let's try plaintext.<br/>
bommdidumpidudidoo</p>

<p id="output"></p>

//----JS------------------------//    
var s = $('p').html();
var matches = s.match( /.*(plaintext)/g );

write(matches);
write(matches[0]);
write(matches[1]);



//------- whatever -------//
function write(s) {
    $('#output').html( $('#output').html() +'<br/>'+s );
}

// output:
// Let's try plaintext
// Let's try plaintext
// undefined
```

» [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u1ovj5do/)
(I've used my custom function `write` instead of `console.log` so that the result would show up in the fiddle)

Why is the third line undefined? I don't understand!

I'm *pretty* sure the expression is right. I'm 1oo% certain that this is the right capturing group syntax for JavaScript, and that `.match()` returns an array with the full match first, then all capturing groups. I've even tested it with regex101.com – over there, I do get the capturing group.

It's not the same as [this other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510793/regex-capturing-group-doesnt-recognise-group1-despite-matches-true) because there, the OR logic was the crux of the problem and here the pipe `|` doesn't even come up.

Comment: That other thread is related but how is it a duplicate? Neither was I asking about quotation marks, nor did any of the answers mark the `g` modifier as the cause for `.match()` not returning capturing groups.

Answer (score 1):

Oooh! It's because I'm doing a global search, with the `g` modifier. I do get the expected result if I remove that modifier. Tss.

I've used that modifier in the first place in order to grab multiple placeholders, but I guess I can still while-loop that stuff …